# Merge 2 Multi-dimensional arrays with some duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that sometimes have matching keys, and I need to merge these values based on the matching fields (make/model/year) and set accordingly based on a value flag each array object has (in this case either **fit: B or fit: R**)

The first array looks like this and contains fit B's:

```
$firstArray = [
 { Model: Aston Martin, Make: V12, Year: 2012, fit: B, front_fit: 52, rear_fit: null}
]
```

Here is the second array and it contains only fit R's:

```
$secondArray = [
 { Model: Aston Martin, Make: V12, Year: 2012, fit: R, front_fit: null, rear_fit: 24}
]
```

Notice how most of the values are the same except fit and the front or rear fit based on that flag (B or R). Ideally I would like to merge these two in a new array that would remove the fit and fill out the front_fit and rear_fit fields accordingly:

```
$mergedNewArray = [
 { Model: Aston Martin, Make: V12, Year: 2012, front_fit: 52, rear_fit: 24}
]
```

There is a potential third scenario to happen where there may not be a matching model/make/year object in one of the arrays, if this is the case I still want to include the existing record in the new array

so it would turn into something like this:

```
$mergedNewArray = [
 { Model: Aston Martin, Make: V12, Year: 2012, front_fit: 52, rear_fit: 24},
  //This has no matching object to merge with but should still be in this array
 { Model: Dodge, Make: Charger, Year: 2006, front_fit: null, rear_fit: 80} 
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated, The less verbose the better

Edit: Added clarification for the first array and second array containing specific fits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to re-index the first array by the make/model/year, and then iterate over the second array, looking for the same car and if found, updating the record, otherwise creating a new entry in the output. The result array can then be re-indexed numerically using `array_values`:

```
$firstArray = json_decode('[
 { "Model": "Aston Martin", "Make": "V12", "Year": 2012, "fit": "B", "front_fit": 52, "rear_fit": null },
 { "Model": "Aston Martin", "Make": "Vantage", "Year": 2017, "fit": "B", "front_fit": 40, "rear_fit": null }
]', true);

$secondArray =json_decode('[
 { "Model": "Aston Martin", "Make": "V12", "Year": 2012, "fit": "R", "front_fit": null, "rear_fit": 24 },
 { "Model": "Dodge", "Make": "Charger", "Year": 2006, "fit": "R", "front_fit": null, "rear_fit": 80 }
]', true);

$result = array();
// index the first array by the model, make and year
foreach ($firstArray as $car) {
    unset($car['fit']);
    $key = $car['Model'] . '#' . $car['Make'] . '#' . $car['Year'];
    $result[$key] = $car;
}

foreach ($secondArray as $car) {
    $key = $car['Model'] . '#' . $car['Make'] . '#' . $car['Year'];
    // have we seen this car?
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        // if so, update
        $result[$key]['rear_fit'] = $car['rear_fit'];
    }
    else {
        // create a new entry
        unset($car['fit']);
        $result[$key] = $car;
    }
}
// reindex to numeric keys
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Model] => Aston Martin
            [Make] => V12
            [Year] => 2012
            [front_fit] => 52
            [rear_fit] => 24
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Model] => Aston Martin
            [Make] => Vantage
            [Year] => 2017
            [front_fit] => 40
            [rear_fit] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Model] => Dodge
            [Make] => Charger
            [Year] => 2006
            [front_fit] => 
            [rear_fit] => 80
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NUo23)

Comment: I think this is close but I should of clarified, the first array will only ever contain fit B's and the second array will only ever  contain fit R's, so I believe the conditional would never be hit in the second for loop

Comment: @BRose in that case you can simplify the `foreach` over `$secondArray`. See my edit; I've also expanded the sample data to have an unmatched value in the first array too.

Comment: Thanks that was the route I ended up taking and it worked pretty well, much appreciated!